# Parsing HTML with Xpath

Tags: html, dom, selenium, xpath

I have the following web page which I am trying to parse with xpath.

For the first table the xpath `//*[@id="eForm"]/table[1]` is working fine and for the second table the xpath `//*[@id="eForm"]/table[2]` is working fine.

However what I would like to do is not use relatives in my statement in case the page order changes.

For the second table it follows a span id of Agent. Can anyone tell me if I can specify in xpath the table following a span ID?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>


</head>
<body class="frame">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="maincontent">
            <h1>Details</h1>
            <br>
            <form name="Form" method="post" action="xxx" id="eForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="xxx" />


                <table class="summary">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                               SUmmary Heading
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th width="40%">

                        </th>
                        <td>
                            ABC Ltd
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                             Number
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            1234
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Company Type
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            Normal Type
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Office
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            Street Address is Here
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Date of Incorporation
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            24/02/2014
                        </td>
                    </tr>




                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            LIVE
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                <span id="Agent">
                    <br>
                </span>
                <table class="summary">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                Agent Details
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th width="40%">
                            Registered Agent
                        </th>
                        <td>ABC COMPANY LIMITED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                             Agent Address
                        </th>
                        <td>Street Address</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>


                <!----><br>
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answring you question - yes. To do that you can you such xpath:

```
//form[@id='eForm']//span[@id='Agent']//table[@class='summary']
```

Also you can use this xpath to identify 1-st table:

```
//form[@id='eForm']//table//thead//th[text()='SUmmary Heading']
```

And this to identify 2-nd table:

```
//form[@id='eForm']//table//thead//th[text()='Agent Details']
```

In this case you don't need to use relatives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't get this to work in my application - Are there any tools to help check out the syntax against a know web page?

Comment: @John, you can use FireFoxe's Firebug+Firepath plugins.
BTW, I've edited initial answer, `//[@id='eForm']` had to be `//form[@id='eForm']` or `//*[@id='eForm']`

Comment: @Alexander, thank you for correcting my answer.

John as Alexander said you can check your xpathes using Firebug. Please let me know if you still having some issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath `following-sibling` to specify an element following another element. Example for your case :

```
//form[@id='eForm']/span[@id='Agent']/following-sibling::table
```

Or you can try another way; select table having preceding `<span id="Agent">` element :

```
//form[@id='eForm']/table[preceding-sibling::span[@id='Agent']]
```